# Extra right margin on iPhone

Tags: iphone, css, mobile-safari

I'm editing our News site's mobile CSS file. On the iPhone 3gs, 4 & simulator there are some pages (not all) there is an extra right margin.

Here's an example of a page WITH the extra margin:

http://bit.ly/mMA2q7

..and here's an example of a page without it:

http://bit.ly/iQeOGY

Both pages are using the same template. I'm guessing the images are adding the extra margin.

Here is our mobile CSS file http://bit.ly/iW5JVm and viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=1;"/>
```

I tried applying different min-width values to the body but haven't found a solution.

Do you know how to get rid of this extra margin on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your photobanner div is too wide. It gets set to 500px which is way too much :)

try to add `width:auto!important` to it :)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, I fixed it adding this code in header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1100" />
```